# How to know who created a tag?

Tags: support, tags, badges

**Taxonomist** badge description states:

> Create a tag used by 50 questions

and I was wondering if there's a way to know which tags were created by me.

So I searched on [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/queries) and I found [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/337636/taxonomist-badges-for-a-user), but it clearly does not work well because it says that I created [mario-kart-8](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mario-kart-8) and [wrath-of-the-lamb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wrath-of-the-lamb) tags, and as you can see in their relative info page [Mario Kart 8](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/mario-kart-8/info) and [Wrath of the lamb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/wrath-of-the-lamb/info) have different creators.

I've noticed that not every tag has a creator in the Tag info page, how does this work? Does it appear only after *Taxonomist* badge is awarded to the creator?

**EDIT:**
My theory seems incorrect, [binding-of-isaac-rebirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binding-of-isaac-rebirth) is tagged by 132 questions (so eligible to *Taxonomist* badge) but it does not have a creator.

Comment: I know the author of that query.  It looks at the tag wiki author, not the tag creator.

Comment: @JAL Then it has nothing to do with taxonomist badge

Comment: Note that Taxonomist is a one-time only badge: The first [BOI: Rebirth Question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/190525/28182) was asked by 3Ventic, who had [already earned Taxonomist](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=51318) for [[tag:banished]] - which does list him as creator. It's likely the tag info page only shows the 'creator' if they've actually earned Taxonomist for 'creating' that tag...

Comment: ^Likewise to the above, I created [[tag:pokemon-go]] which doesn't list a 'creator' as I had previously earned Taxonomist for [[tag:pokemon-oras]]

Comment: @Robotnik Oh, thank you for clarifying that. But is it possible to know which tags were created by me?

Comment: @pinckerman - Not easily - likely the only way would be to look through your 'tags' on your profile, then check who asked the first question (and even that can potentially be incorrect if the tag was added to an older question after-the-fact).

Comment: @Robotnik Ok, I give up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some stuff I've figured out:

- The person who first **uses** the tag is the person who 'created' it - either by asking a question with it, or by editing it onto a question (with some caveats to do with deletion, merging and renaming tags).
- There is a difference between creating a **tag** (i.e. using it on a question for the first time), and creating the **tag wiki/excerpt** (the informational pieces of the tag).

  - For the purposes of the Taxonomist badge (and the *"created by"* text on the tag info page) we care about the former.

Now, let's take a look at the Taxonomist badge:

[image: Taxonomist: Create a tag used by 50 questions: 162 awarded]

So wait, why is there only 162 badges awarded if we have [over 260 tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/612830/count-of-tags-relevant-to-taxonomist) with >= 50 questions? Well that's because you can only earn Taxonomist **once**, and those other tags have been created by members who have already earned Taxonomist on another tag.

You can click on the [Taxonomist](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) badge on the Badge page to see a list of all users who have been awarded the badge thus far and for which tag it was awarded. Going to that tag's info page will then show that the tag was created by that user.

For example: I was awarded the badge for creating [pokemon-oras](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-oras) but not [pokemon-go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-go), the former lists me as a creator but the latter doesn't. Likewise, in your example of *Binding of Issac: Rebirth*: 3ventic was awarded the badge for creating [banished](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/banished) and his name appears on that tag's info page, but not the [binding-of-isaac-rebirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binding-of-isaac-rebirth) tag page, despite asking the [initial question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/190525/28182).

Thus the tag info page only shows the 'creator' if they've actually earned Taxonomist for 'creating' that tag.

---

To directly answer your question: **How to know who created a tag?**

- View the tag's info page and look for the creator, or
- Search for it in the [Taxonomist awards page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) by clicking on the Badge on the Badge page and browsing the awards.

If it isn't in one of those places and the 50 question threshold has been met, it's either created by someone who already has the badge (either by asking a question or by editing it in to someone else's), or created by someone who has left the site, and you will need to manually search for it:

1. Navigate to the first question asked in that tag (by using the 'newest' tab and going to the last page)

   - A lot of the time, this will the be tag 'creator', but may not be if the tag has been added after-the-fact or if the initial question was deleted.
   - Check any edits to see if the tag was added at a later date. If it has, there's no easy way to determine which was 'first' save for cross referencing edit dates.
2. If the OP (or editor) still exists on the site, visit their profile badge list and look for Taxonomist.

   - If they have it awarded, clicking on the badge will show which tag they got it for.
   - If the OP doesn't exist anymore (is anonymous or had their account removed, then the Taxonomist badge is 'lost' for this tag - it can never be awarded).
   - If the OP doesn't have the badge, and there are no edits to their initial question that add the tag, then it's likely the actual 'first question' has been deleted, and - contrary to what I thought earlier - only mods can search for deleted questions to determine this.

This is the only general way I can think of to manually determine who 'created' a tag. There are probably some SEDE queries to help with the majority of this searching (except for deleted questions which aren't available on SEDE)

Comment: This is probably the most we can do about this and I'll accept your answer, although my initial question "which tags were created by me" still remains. I've looked several SEDE queries but they don't seem to work properly, I always get strange results. As I said, I give up.

Comment: With regard to searching for deleted questions, even if you have the reputation such that you can use the ‘deleted:yes’ parameter, you can still only see your own deleted posts through search. It's not a matter of reputation for option 3, it's whether you're a diamond mod or not.

Comment: @grgarside huh. It's hard to keep track of what is a mod permission vs a 10k+ permission, I could've sworn I was able to search deleted stuff before modship :-)

Answer (score 4):

So I don't know the full internal workings of the tag system, but I know that if a tag is renamed or merged the creator of the new tag will be the person who performed the merge. *However*, I know that this is taken into account in the taxonomist logic, so if you create a tag and it's renamed you still get the badge.

Comment: Oh this is useful. But what's wrong with "t̨ag͘ sys͜t͡em̧" text?

Comment: @pinckerman Not sure, it just happens every time I type *tag ͞sys̢tem*

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't see a straight forward way of pulling this out of the data.

The following query will list all the tags you changed via your edits:

```
select text, creationdate from posthistory where userid = 87579 and text like '%<%>%'
```

You will need to manually check the tags.  I guess that once you are okay with them you can update the query's where clause to include a creationdate after your last manual check.  Note that the results will also show entries if you used "<" and ">" characters.

However, for questions it seems a lot trickier.  You can use this query:

```
select tags, creationdate from posts where owneruserid = 87579 and posttypeid = 1 and lasteditdate is null
```

This will give you tags used for all your questions where there have been no future edits.  If there was an edit, and it was by you, the previous query should show tag changes.

I didn't manage to write a query that allowed you to see all the original tags in edited questions.  For example, if you create a new question that has since been edited to remove tags.  You will need to join a modified version of the 2 previous queries to check for tag changes on your questions.

Finally, I haven't looked at tag merging.

---

> I've noticed that not every tag has a creator in the Tag info page, how does this work? Does it appear only after Taxonomist badge is awarded to the creator?

I think you are correct.  Oddly, none of these tags have a listed owner:

```
select * from tags where count = 50
```

But these do:

```
select * from tags where count = 51
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for the proof. Btw the only table with a *OwnerUserId* is *TagSynonyms*, I have no idea where the tag owner is saved.

Comment: @pinckerman - the listed owner could be driven by a join on the badges table

Comment: I want to find the tags created by me, but if I run `select * from TagSynonyms where OwnerUserId = 87579` I get an empty list, so a join won't give me anything.

Comment: @pinckerman - That would suggest you have no tag synonyms.  Is that correct?

Comment: Right, but I have created tags. I don't know where to find the owner in the database. I doubt the tag owner is searched in the Taxonomist badge owners.

Comment: @pinckerman - There is nothing in the tag table to show the owner. It is going to be a case of some long winded table joins to get the data in one query.  From the available data it seems that the owner is populated only when the badge table is populated, and appears to only occur when the `count` is 51 (as seen in the current data).

Comment: It seems plausible that when the badge is earned this triggers the owner binding. But I don't understand, they have to keep trace of the owner once a tag is created in some way. Btw you may be right, the whole query is probably long and complex to replicate.

Comment: I've found an exception to your theory: [binding-of-isaac-rebirth](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/binding-of-isaac-rebirth/info) is tagged 132 times but does not have a creator.

Comment: This scenario explained in this answer: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/12208/101016