# Why is this tag without me as the author?

Tags: support, tags, badges

I was reading [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12193/how-to-know-who-created-a-tag) about knowing who created a tag and, after looking at the tags they had linked ([like this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/mario-kart-8/info)), I went to visit the tag I had created recently: [space-hulk-deathwing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/space-hulk-deathwing/info).

Unlike the Mario Kart 8 tag, the Deathwing tag has no listed creator. I was hoping someone could tell me why this is and whether or not this tag would count towards the Taxonimist badge for me?

Comment: Mario Kart 8's tag has a body that describes the game - your tag does not.  I wonder if that is why your name doesn't appear along side it?  Or maybe its because not enough questions exist for it.

Comment: @TimmyJim I don't think a lack of questions would do it. My name appeared by the pokemon-sm tag after I put the tag on the first question.

Comment: Maybe its because so far santyclause is the only one who has asked questions for it so far.  I'm just trying to come up with possible reasons.

Comment: @Vemonus Are you sure you appeared as the creator before 50 questions tagged? I've searched a lot of tags and so far only those related to a Taxonomist badge have a creator, those with <50 questions have not.

Comment: @pinckerman yes, definitely. When I saw my name by the tag, I knew I'd finally be able to get Taxonomist :P

Comment: @Vemonus Did you create "pokemon-sun" and "pokemon-moon" synonyms, too? After looking on the database tables I've found that when a synonym is created an *OwnerUserId* is stored, unlike tags.

Comment: @pinckerman no, I believe Robotnik created those and made them synonyms just for future reference.

Comment: @Vemonus Yep, Robotnik added them. I don't know if that affected the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I discovered after researching for [this answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12208/28182), a tag creator is defined as the person who initially creates the tag - either by asking a question, or by editing the tag into a question (not necessarily their own question) after-the-fact.

The tag will only show a 'creator' on the info page IFF:

- There are more than 50 questions
- Said 'creator' was awarded the '[Taxonomist](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist)' Badge **for that tag**

Your tag currently has 3 questions, so it doesn't (yet!) qualify.

Comment: Vemonus said [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12206/why-is-this-tag-without-me-as-the-author#comment38330_12206) he appeared as the creator for *pokemon-sm* before the 50 questions threshold, this is confusing.

Comment: @pinckerman - Vemonus 'created' the tag by editing it onto a question, and was [awarded Taxonomist](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=162442) as such. I have edited this to make it clearer

Comment: You misunderstand me, he states his name appeared as the creator **before** awarding Taxonimist badge.

Comment: @pinckerman - So far I've been unable to see that reproduced on any tag with < 50 questions, including tags where synonyms have been added. I'm not saying it doesn't happen, just that I haven't seen hard evidence of it yet.

Comment: I'm like 90% sure my name was by the tag prior to getting the badge, but it's not really possible for me to prove that anymore :(