# Tag Creator Credit

Tags: support, tags

I just finished creating the [pokemon-duel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-duel) description, tag wiki, and its excerpt and got those edits approved. However, the creator of the actual tag is Community (according to what it looks like).

So, my question is, if the Community user created the tag, who gets the credit for creating the tag?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12193/how-to-know-who-created-a-tag)

Comment: Related - http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12206/why-is-this-tag-without-me-as-the-author

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, 'creating' a tag and creating the tag's Wiki and Excerpt are separate processes. From my answer on the [link](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12193/how-to-know-who-created-a-tag) Vemonus linked above:

> - The person who first **uses** the tag is the person who 'created' it - either by asking a question with it, or by editing it onto a question (with some caveats to do with deletion, merging and renaming tags).
> - There is a difference between creating a **tag** (i.e. using it on a question for the first time), and creating the **tag wiki/excerpt** (the informational pieces of the tag).

---

As to Community 'owning' the creation of the Tag Wiki: this happens whenever someone under 20k reputation suggests an edit to a Tag Wiki.

My guess is, Tag Wikis and Excerpts do not automatically exist in Stack Exchange's databases when a tag is created. I'm not privvy as to why, but I speculate it has to do with not wanting to insert blank rows into the DBs for performance and storage reasons (especially as extraneous tags can be deleted off of questions with relative ease).

However, once you suggest an edit to the Tag Wiki, it needs something previous to compare against for the purposes of the review/edit system. Thus, 'Community' creates a blank tag wiki and excerpt, so that your suggested edit is displayed as a 'revision' correctly.

---

If you take a look at the [Community user](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile), you can see it's just a bot account that handles a variety of functions:

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
> - Own suggested edits from anonymous users
> - Remove abandoned questions

Comment: I knew the Community user was a background process already.

Comment: @Yoshi24517 - No worries, just covering all bases. What about the rest of it? Anything I can clarify?

Comment: Pinging not showing up in my comments for some reason, but, say 50 questions were tagged under the `pokemon-duel` tag, who would get the badge? Me, or the other guy?

Comment: @Yoshi24517 - It will remove the ping if you're responding to the post OP and there's noone else commenting. Don't worry, I still get notified. In the case of the Pokemon Duel tag, Garret would get it - he 'created' the tag by asking a question on it.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks for your help! (Darn it, I wanted to make the tag...)